# How to update task tracker that my mapper is still running fine as opposed to generating timeout?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I forgot what API/method to call, but my problem is that :

My mapper will run more than 10 minutes - and I don't want to increase default timeout.

Rather I want to have my mapper send out update ping to task tracker, when it is in the particular code path that consumes time > 10 mins.

Please let me know what API/method to call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply increase a counter and call `progress`. This will ensure that the task sends a heartbeat back to the tasktracker to know if its alive.

In the new API this is managed through the context, see here: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/api/index.html

e.G.

```
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // increment counter
    context.getCounter(SOME_ENUM).increment(1);
    context.progress();
}
```

In the old API there is the reporter class:
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reporter.html

Answer (score 1):

You typically use the [Reporter](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reporter.html) to let the framework know you're still alive.

Quote from the javadoc:

> Mapper and Reducer can use the Reporter provided to report progress or
>   just indicate that they are alive. **In scenarios where the application
>   takes an insignificant amount of time to process** individual key/value
>   pairs, **this is crucial since the framework might assume that the task
>   has timed-out** and kill that task.