# How to avoid from failing Map/Reduce task in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a loop with too many iterations and a function which is computation heavy in Reducer function.

```
while (context.getCounter(SOLUTION_FLAG.SOLUTION_FOUND).getValue() < 1 && itrCnt < MAX_ITR)
```

MAX_ITR is iterations count - user input

The problem is when I run it on Hadoop cluster there is timeout error and Reducer task is killed

```
17/05/06 21:09:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1494129392154_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1494129392154_0001_r_000000_0 Timed out after 600 secs
```

What should I do to avoid timeout? (My guess is heartbeat signals.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the timeouts might be a long-running computation in reducer without reporting the job progress ststus back to the Hadoop framework. You can try increasing the timeout interval from default 600 sec using below command.

```
mapred.task.timeout=1800000
```

Here is more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281307/the-reduce-fails-due-to-task-attempt-failed-to-report-status-for-600-seconds-ki) on this.

If these settings doesn't works  then consider rechecking the code. There could be an issue with code logic too.

Comment: Actually, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11815803/7584363) one solved the issue perfectly but the reference link was good. Thanks